# conditional IF logic with date field type

Tags: c#, asp.net, conditional-statements, formview

This is more of a syntax question (I think), but I've been struggling with it.

We created a user defined field in our ERP system.  Instead of NULLs, the ERP fills it with 1753-01-01 00:00:00.000.  I have a form view control that references this UDF.  I want to be able to conditionally hide the date if it is that 1753 value.

So I want to do the following in the ASP page (not the codebehind):

If field = 1753-01-01 00:00:00.000, then value = ""
If field != 1753-01-01 00:00:00.000, then value = field

Here's my label:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblReactDate" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("UDF_ML_REACT", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>' />
```

I want to do something like:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblReactDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UDF_ML_REACT")%> == "1753-01-01 00:00:00.000" ? "" : <%# Bind("UDF_ML_REACT")%>'
```

I've tried a few variations, and seem to think I've hit a syntax wall, or this cannot be done.  I think what is also throwing me off is the date formatting.

Comment: You dont want to do it at server side. Just get hold of control in Javascript and set the value using a conditional statement. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479011.aspx

Comment: i don't mind doing it server side, I just thought there'd be an easy way to modify the ASPX file instead of writing code behind to do it. This is an intranet page, so I wanted to do it w/o writing a lot of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change Bind to Eval, since you are not using the Label for two way databinding, also you need to cast to string for using ==

```
<asp:Label ID="lblReactDate" runat="server" 
     Text='<%# Eval("UDF_ML_REACT").ToString() == "1753-01-01 00:00:00.000" 
                  ? "" : Eval("UDF_ML_REACT", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")%>' />
```

or

```
<asp:Label ID="lblReactDate" runat="server" 
     Text='<%# Eval("UDF_ML_REACT","{0:yyyy}").ToString() == "1753" 
                  ? "" : Eval("UDF_ML_REACT", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")%>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another "variation" for you to try, in case the others donT work:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblReactDate" runat="server"  Text='<%# (string)DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.UDF_ML_REACT") == "1753-01-01 00:00:00.000" ? "" : DataBinder.Eval(Container, "UDF_ML_REACT")%>'  />
```